# Regular expression default value

Tags: regex, jmeter

Jmeter passes default value when trying to fetch a part of response in my case is a unique name which I want to pass in next request but it takes default value:

```
{"status":"success","body":{"uniqueName":"jpr1444130495897","voucherType":"sales","transactions":[{"creditAccount":{"uniqueName":"acctomerge","name":"Mayank"},"debitAccount":{"uniqueName":"dacc","name":"dummyaccount"},"amount":2228}],"voucherNo":1912,"date":"01-09-2015","tag":"dummydata","description":"Q3goK8QrUo"}}
```

In above response I have to capture `uniquename` & pass it in my next request. But by default it take default value.

Bean shell assertion contains:

```
${__setProperty(uniqueName,${uniqueName})}
```

Next request is this.

Still fetching default value. Somebody please help.

Comment: Not that I understand the question, but that's JSON, so use a JSON parser, not regex.

Answer (score 0):

As [Biffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen) said it is better to use JSON Path Extractor that comes with jmeter plugins (http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/). It's a lot easier for JSON - just put JSON path (probably in your case just uniqueName will be enough, but you can put there $.body.uniqueName) add a variable name as uniqueName as well, so there will be no problem to use it later as ${uniqueName} in the next request. And that's it.

Oh, and your post suggests that you try to extract it with Beanshell assertion instead of Regular Expression Extractor by the way - that also can be a case.

Comment: HI guys thanks for the input . i have used regular expression like this {"uniqueName":"(.+?)","voucherType" was able to  handle with regex . 

Thanks again for solution will try json path extractor also

Comment: Should the json extractor also be able to extract into properties? Example property: ${__P(uniqueName)}

Comment: Nevermind, it only extracts to variables local to the jmeter thread.

Answer (score 0):

What exact `uniqueName` you need to extract? There are 3 of them in your JSON data:

1. jpr1444130495897
2. acctomerge
3. dacc

[image]

It isn't necessary to convert variable to property to use in next request. If both requests live in the same thread group - it's enough to use reference name like `${uniqueName}`

For JSON data it's more handy to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project). See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for plugin installation and usage instructions.

Comment: HI guys thanks for the input . i have used regular expression like this {"uniqueName":"(.+?)","voucherType" was able to  handle with regex . 

Thanks again for solution will try json path extractor also